# Estimate the order of the integral with respect to the parameter

Tags: calculus

Show that for all $\epsilon\in(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$
$$I(x)\triangleq\int_\epsilon^\frac{\pi}{4} e^{-x\sin^2 t} dt = \left(1+O(\frac{1}{x\epsilon^2})\right)\frac{e^{-x\sin ^2 \epsilon}- e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin 2\epsilon}{x\sin2\epsilon}$$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

Here I write $f(x;\epsilon) = O(\frac{1}{x\epsilon^2})$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$meaning $$f(x)\leq M\frac{1}{x\epsilon^2}$$for all sufficient large $x$. Here $M>0$ is an absolute constant not related to $\epsilon$.

Actually there is another part:

Show that for any $x>0$ $$\int_0^\epsilon e^{-x\sin^2t}dt = \left(1+O(x\epsilon^4)\right)\int_0^\epsilon e^{-xt^2}dt$$ as  $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$. This can be proved using Taylor expansion.

And together we can estimate the integral$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-x\sin^2t}dt\sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}}$$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

And here is my trial: if we apply Laplace's method, we will have 
$$I(x)\sim \frac{e^{-x\sin^2 \epsilon}}{x\sin2\epsilon}$$
Details can be found on P34 of this [note](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/ae.pdf). Now we only need to show
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-x\sin^2 \epsilon}}{x\sin2\epsilon} &= \left(1+O(\frac{1}{x\epsilon^2})\right)\frac{e^{-x\sin ^2 \epsilon}- e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin 2\epsilon}{x\sin2\epsilon}\\
\iff \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin 2\epsilon}{e^{-x\sin ^2 \epsilon}- e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin 2\epsilon} & = O(\frac{1}{x\epsilon^2})\\
\iff~~~~~~~ \frac{x\epsilon^2 \sin 2\epsilon}{e^{-\frac{x}{2}\sin ^2 \epsilon}- \sin 2\epsilon} & = O(1)
\end{align}
So my question is what is wrong with my calculation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get proper parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: What does $O\left(\frac1{x\epsilon^2}\right)$ mean here? You fix $\epsilon\in(0,\frac\pi4)$, and then you let $x\to\infty$. Then $\epsilon$ is a fixed parameter and $O\left(\frac1{x\epsilon^2}\right)$ would be no different than $O\left(\frac1x\right)$. It looks a bit as if you actually have a limit $\epsilon\to0$ in mind somewhere? Or perhaps you want $x\epsilon^2\to\infty$?

Comment: @joriki I added something to make it more clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't made it any clearer. You added another equally meaningless asymptotic, this time with roles switched, where now $x$ is fixed and $\epsilon$ undergoes a limit process, yet $x$ appears in the asymptotic expression $O(x\epsilon^4)$ as if it weren't a constant. Are you aware of the definition of the $O()$ notation?

Comment: @joriki Yes you are right. I should first make this limit process more clear.